AWS lambda give permission to assume role
I want to use role assume in a AWS lambda function.
I have the follow template.yml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Parameters:
  Role1:
    Type: String
Resources:
  Function1:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: core.lambda_function.lambda_handler
      Policies:
        - Statement:
            - Sid: AssumeRol
              Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - sts:AssumeRole
              Resource: '*'
      Environment:
        Variables:
          ROLE: !Ref Role1

And in lambda python the follow code:
role_arn = get_role_arn_from_env_parameter()
assumed_role_object = sts_client.assume_role(
                    RoleArn=role_arn,
                    RoleSessionName="AssumeRoleSession")

But I get the follow error when functions is executed:
ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation:
User: "..." is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: "..."

It seems Policy Statement AssumeRol does not work or maybe should be put in other place ?
EDIT:
trusted role policy:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}


sts:AssumeRole needs to be added to the iam role policy not the lambda resource policy

I also added to the role but does not work

Can you post the trusted policy of the role that you are trying to assume?

The User: "..."  bit seems wrong since it should be using a role. What information is specified in that part? Is it an ARN or just a name? Does it mention /user or /role?

You know that the Lambda function is launched with a configurable IAM role, yes? You specifically want that IAM role to be able to assume another, different IAM role?
